# How do I send a for loop item to a method

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am attempting to attach an AlumbId to an image src tag. what I have found is that I need to use a method to use the link and send it back. I'm not sure if this is the best way but I have that working fine but for some reason the method is sending the AlumbId as 'undefined' so I am not getting an image back.

```
<template>
<div id="tracks">
  <div id="track"  v-for="track in tracks" :key='track.id'>
    <img class="cover" :src="getAlbumImg(track.albumId)" />
    <div class=content-name>{{track.albumName}}</div>
    <div class="artist-name">{{track.artistName}}</div>
    <audio controls class= "audio">
      <source type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>

  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
  name: 'Tracks',
  data () {
    return {
      tracks: []
    }
  },
  created() {
    axios.get('http://api.napster.com/v2.2/tracks/top?apikey=YTkxZTRhNzAtODdlNy00ZjMzLTg0MWItOTc0NmZmNjU4Yzk4')
    .then(response => {
      // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
      this.tracks = response.data
    })
    .catch(e => {
      this.errors.push(e)
    })
  },
  methods: {
    getAlbumImg: function(albumId) {
      return 'http://direct.rhapsody.com/imageserver/v2/albums/' + albumId + '/images/300x300.jpg';
    }
  }
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: `this.tracks = response.data` should be `this.tracks = response.data.tracks`

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that I was trying to use the object tracks instead of the array within the object.